# Room (AAC): [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "group": syntax error)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Following Dao doesn't build in my Android App:

```
@Dao
interface GroupDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(group: Group)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM group")
    fun loadAll(): LiveData<List<Group>>
}
```

When I build the project in Android Studio 3 I get the following error on gradle build step:

:app:kaptDebugKotlin

> e:
>   C:\workspaces\SystemicConsensusKotlin\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\de\maxdobler\systemicconsensus\group\GroupDao.java:13:
>   error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
>   missing database (near "group": syntax error)
>
> e:     public abstract
>   android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData>
>   loadAll();

If I remove the loadAll function everything works like a charm...
What is the problem with this function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved keyword in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). You cannot name a table (or anything else) `GROUP`. Use the `tableName` property on the `@Entity` annotation to rename the table to something else, then use that table name in your `@Query`.